# Expo SDK 37: upgrading to react-native-webview@8.1.1 broke onShouldStartLoadWithRequest functionality for undefined deeplinks

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

My original code was working before upgrading to Expo SDK 37 and `react-native-webview@8.1.1`:

```
const onShouldStartLoadWithRequest = ({ url }: WebViewNavigation): boolean => {
    const response = parseResponse(url);
    if (shouldProceed(response)) {
        proceed(response);
        return false;
    }
    return response;
};

parseResponse(url: string): Params | boolean {
    const uri = URL.parse(url);
    if (uri.protocol === "deeplinkprotocol:") {
        const query = queryString.parse(uri.search, { decode: false });
        switch (uri.host) {
        case Event.connected:
            return {
                param: query.param,
            };
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

    return uri.protocol === this.http || uri.protocol === this.https;
}
```

The redirection to the request url stopped working since `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work after the update, I needed to add the `originWhitelist` prop to `WebView`:

```
<WebView originWhitelist={[ "https://", "deeplinkprotocol://" ]} onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} {...props} />
```

Hope this helps.